# Calculating the Expected life of network with hazard functions

Tags: mathematical-statistics, survival, reliability, hazard, networks

I have been asked to solve some questions in the statistical program R.

First, I want to find the expected life length (by numeric integration) of a network with 3 parallel components (T1,T2,T3) and 1 serial component (T4).

[image]

The hazard functions of the components are:  $\\$

$\lambda_{T1}(t) = \lambda_{T2}(t) = \lambda_{T3}(t) =\frac{1}{2*\sqrt(t)}$, and $\lambda_{T4} = \frac{t^{11/10}}{50}$

From my understanding, to be able to calculate the expected life length, I want to find the survival function of the network which leads me to

$E[T] = \int_{0}^{inf}S(t) dt$.

I know that the hazard function is

$ \lambda_{T}(t)$ = $-\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}log S_{T}(t) $

and thus

$S_{T}(t) = exp(- \int_{0}^{t}\lambda_{T}(t) dt.$    (Survival function = Cumulative hazard function)

My first problem is that I have no idea how to find the survival function S(t) when I´m dealing with network components?

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that since the problem is not supposed to be solved explicitly, the solution is to estimate the expected life length via simulation. The life length of the system is $$T = \min((\max(T_1, T_2, T_3), T_4),$$ if you generate many monte carlo realisations $T^*_b$ of this variable, the estimate of the expected life length is $$\frac{1}{B}\sum_{b=1}^B T^*_b.$$

If you want to do the numerical integration of the survival function by a simpson type approach to find the expectation instead of monte carlo, the survival function of the system is

\begin{align*}
S(t) &= 1 - P(T \leq t)\\
&= 1 - P(\min(\max(T_1, T_2, T_2), T_4) \leq t)\\
&= 1 - (1 - P(\min(\max(T_1, T_2, T_2), T_4) > t))\\
&= P(\min(\max(T_1, T_2, T_2), T_4) > t)\\
&= P(\max(T_1, T_2, T_2) > t)P(T_4 > t)\\
&= (1 - P(\max(T_1, T_2, T_2) \leq t))(1 - P(T_4 \leq t))\\
&= (1 - P(T_1 \leq t)P(T_2 \leq t)P(T_3 \leq t))(1 - P(T_4 \leq t))\\
&= (1 - F_1(t)F_2(t)F_3(t))(1 - F_4(t))\\
&= (1 - F_1(t)^3)(1 - F_4(t)).
\end{align*}
where the last equality is due to that $F_1(t)=F_2(t)=F_3(t)$. Also,
$F_1(t)= 1 - \exp(-t^{\frac{1}{2}}), $ and $F_4(t) = 1 - \exp(-\frac{1}{105}t^{21/10}).$

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick reply Simon.

Comment: So basically all I need to do is to Integrate $(1-F_{1}(t)..*F_{3}(t)*(1-F_{4}(t))$ to get my expected life length?

How does the hazard function look like for the whole interval then? I`ll get confused when there exist hazard functions of several components. U got any idea or tips regarding this matter?

Comment: The hazard function of the lifetime of the system is 
$$ \lambda_T(t) = -\frac{d}{dt}\log(S(t)) = \frac{3F_1(t)^2\frac{dF_1(t)}{dt}}{1 - F_1(t)^3} + \frac{\frac{dF_4(t)}{dt}}{1 - F_4(t)},$$
since F_1(t)=F_2(t)=F_3(t).

Comment: And yes, just integrate the survival $$S(t) = (1 - F_1(t)F_2(t)F_3(t))(1 - F_4(t)) = (1 - F_1(t)^3)(1 - F_4(t)),$$ from $0$ to $\infty.$

Comment: You sure it suppose to be 

$S(t) = (1-(F_{1}(t)^{3})(1-F_{4}(t)))$ and not   

$S(t) = (1-(F_{1}(t)^{3})*(F_{4}(t))$

I am suspicious because $F_{4}$ is serial connected to $F_{1,2,3}.$

Comment: And what is the prob that a failure of the network is due to a certain component, lets say T4 in my example? 

From my understanding, this is Prob(T = $T_{4}$). 
Which must imply $T_{1,2,3} > T_{4}$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, if you correct the parenteses so that it reads $S(t) = (1 - F_1(t)^3)(1 - F_4(t)).$

Comment: Yes, the probability that the system fails due to component 4 would be $P(T_4 < \min(T_1, T_2, T_3)).$

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the solution $T = \min((\max(T_1, T_2, T_3), T_4),$. Here's what I am thinking. i) the solution doesn't contain any information that $T_4$ comes _after_ the parallel system. ii) If the first component is broken, then $T_1 = \infty$, so why would the parallel system, given by  $\max(T_1, T_2, T_3)$, be $\infty$? iii) if $T_4$ is really really small, then $\min((\max(T_1, T_2, T_3), T_4) = T_4$, but why have we discarded the time it takes to complete the parallel system?

Comment: i) Yes it does, the system fails if either all of $T_1$, $T_2$ and $T_3$ fail, or if $T_4$ fails, which is because $T_1$, $T_2$ and $T_3$ are serially connected to $T_4$. Therefore the survival time of the system is the smallest of the survival tie of $T_4$ and the largest of the survival times of $T_1$, $T_2$ and $T_3$.

Comment: ii) if the first component is broken, it breaks at a specific time point, say $t_1$. Then this is the survival time of $T_1$ which could be equal to the maximum of the survival times of the three first components, or smaller.

Comment: iii) I do not understand what you are writing here at all.